# What is the use for emeralds?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently found some emeralds while searching in a cave for some diamonds. Other than creating an emerald block, what other purposes do the emeralds serve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the Wiki:](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Emerald)

> Emerald is an item which was added in the 0.9.0 update, obtainable by mining Emerald Ore. On the PC and Console editions, it is used for trading with villagers. But, as villagers will have degraded AI, trading will not be possible as of yet, so it's only function would be to craft an emerald block and use it as a decorative item. Emeralds can also be obtained from village chests or mineshaft chests, though rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Emerald can be used for trading with villagers. It's also very rare, you might be able to find it by looking in villagers' chests, or you could try mine for it (in a mine or cave) - you probably won't but it is worth a try.

Comment: Just to confirm: This question is about Minecraft **Pocket** Edition, i.e. the mobile version. Do you know if there has been an update? i.e. does your answer now apply to the Pocket Edition?